# Turn words array from a document with their coordinates into sentences

Tags: javascript, algorithm, machine-learning, ocr, document

I have an array of words with their coordinates in the document, I want to turn them into sentences.
My array input:

```
  [
    {
        "bounds": [
          {
            "x": 10,
            "y": 10
          },
          {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 10
          },
          {
            "x": 15,
            "y": 15
          },
          {
            "x": 10,
            "y": 15
          }
        ],
        "desc": "Hey"
      },
    {
        "bounds": [
          {
            "x": 18,
            "y": 10
          },
          {
            "x": 24,
            "y": 10
          },
          {
            "x": 24,
            "y": 15
          },
          {
            "x": 18,
            "y": 15
          }
        ],
        "desc": "Name"
      },
          {
        "bounds": [
          {
            "x": 18,
            "y": 20
          },
          {
            "x": 24,
            "y": 20
          },
          {
            "x": 24,
            "y": 25
          },
          {
            "x": 18,
            "y": 25
          }
        ],
        "desc": "What"
      },
    {
        "bounds": [
          {
            "x": 18,
            "y": 20
          },
          {
            "x": 24,
            "y": 20
          },
          {
            "x": 24,
            "y": 25
          },
          {
            "x": 18,
            "y": 25
          }
        ],
        "desc": "Sup"
      }
]
```

The program output should be:

```
Hey Name
What Sup
```

- The coordinates are not accurate just an example, also the algorithm needs to deal with words that are in the middle of sentences and other extreme cases.

What it the best way I can do it (Ideally implemented with JavaScript)?

Comment: Please explain, how you want to achieve that. Tagging this question with "machine-learning" or "algorithm" doesn't explain what you want to do.

Comment: @MichaelHirschler I'm looking for the best way to do it...

Comment: @gal That adds absolutely nothing to the question. What is "it"? You want to turn an array of words into sentences. What is the structure of the array? What type of sentences do you want to create?

Comment: @victor Sorry for the confusion.. The array is in the question content and also the output, I want to create sentences based on the words location not their meaning. I have an OCR model to find the words location but I dont know how to connect them to sentences.

Comment: @Lora129 exactly !

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table and order it for lines and positions, then get the text in this order back.

```js
var data = [{ bounds: [{ x: 10, y: 10 }, { x: 15, y: 10 }, { x: 15, y: 15 }, { x: 10, y: 15 }], desc: "Hey" }, { bounds: [{ x: 18, y: 10 }, { x: 24, y: 10 }, { x: 24, y: 15 }, { x: 18, y: 15 }], desc: "Name" }, { bounds: [{ x: 18, y: 20 }, { x: 24, y: 20 }, { x: 24, y: 25 }, { x: 18, y: 25 }], desc: "What" }, { bounds: [{ x: 18, y: 20 }, { x: 24, y: 20 }, { x: 24, y: 25 }, { x: 18, y: 25 }], desc: "Sup" }],
    hash = {},
    result;

data.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.bounds[0].y] = hash[a.bounds[0].y] || {};
    hash[a.bounds[0].y][a.bounds[0].x] = hash[a.bounds[0].y][a.bounds[0].x] || [];
    hash[a.bounds[0].y][a.bounds[0].x].push({ desc: a.desc, end: a.bounds[2] });

});

result = Object.keys(hash)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .map(k => Object.keys(hash[k])
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .reduce((r, l) => [...r, ...hash[k][l].map(c => c.desc)], [])
        .join(' ')
    )
    .join('\n');
   
console.log(result);
console.log(hash);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```